# Material UI Select component's customized icon do not vertically center

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-ko1j5?file=/demo.css) is the demo link, right now, the dropdown icon is not vertically center. It seems like it has additional top padding for the icon with class `"tlm-dropdown-icon"`. That extra space cause the icon is not vertical center. I inspect the element, but I do not find out any related padding or margin for the element. Besides, I actually do not understand why the icon have extra space on the top.

```css
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

these CSSseems not doing any work.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the [extrinsic height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS#setting_a_specific_size) of the icon element to a small number, causing it to be overflowed and pushed down (at least that's my assumption). The fix is remove the `height` or set it to `auto` in your custom icon styles so the element can be able to resize itself:

```
height: auto;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

You can also use flex and vertically align it:

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```